# Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CanModifyGuard (UsersService, ?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, node-modules

just when I thought I do understand how the modules work and starting to play with guards which leads me to this error in full

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CanModifyGuard (UsersService, ?). Please make sure that the argument TelevisionsService at index [1] is available in the UsersModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If TelevisionsService is a provider, is it part of the current UsersModule?
- If TelevisionsService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UsersModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing TelevisionsService */ ]
  })
```

`CanModifyGuard` was fine when the guard is using only `TelevisionsService`, once I added the `UsersService` and add the guard into the `UsersController`
The error above popped up.

Wonder if I can have another pair of eyes where I am setting this wrong?

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { UsersModule } from './resources/users/users.module';
import { AuthModule } from './resources/auth/auth.module';
import { CommonModule } from './resources/common/common.module';
import { TelevisionsModule } from './resources/televisions/televisions.module';
import { CurrentUserMiddleware } from './common/middlewares/current-user.middleware';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.DATABASE_URL),
    UsersModule,
    AuthModule,
    CommonModule,
    TelevisionsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(CurrentUserMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

**can-modify.guard.ts**

```js
import {
  CanActivate,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { TelevisionsService } from '../../resources/televisions/televisions.service';
import { UsersService } from '../../resources/users/users.service';

@Injectable()
export class CanModifyGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
    private readonly televisionsService: TelevisionsService,
  ) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    //logics here
  }
}
```

**users.module.ts**

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { User, UserSchema } from './user.entity';
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
  ],
  exports: [UsersService],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

televisions.module.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TelevisionsController } from './televisions.controller';
import { TelevisionsService } from './televisions.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Television, TelevisionSchema } from './television.entity';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: Television.name, schema: TelevisionSchema },
    ]),
    UsersModule,
  ],
  exports: [TelevisionsService],
  controllers: [TelevisionsController],
  providers: [TelevisionsService],
})
export class TelevisionsModule {}
```

auth.module.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import authConfig from './config/auth.config';

@Module({
  imports: [UsersModule, ConfigModule.forFeature(authConfig)],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**common.module.ts** (dont think this file would have any effect but just in case)

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AuthorizationRolesGuard } from '../../common/guards/authorization-roles.guard';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: AuthorizationRolesGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class CommonModule {}
```

In order to use the guard, I added the guard to the specific route `@UseGuards(CanModifyGuard)` and again, it is working fine when I added this guard into television controller but once I added it to user controller the error pops up.

As the error mentioned for potential solutions even though `UsersModule` is not using any of the `TelevisionsService` I still imported `TelevisionsModule` into `UsersModule` but no luck on getting this fix...and instead I would get another error and said potential cause `A circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it.`  I read the doc about it and also tried using `forwardRef()` but still didn't fix it.  I might have put the `forwardRef()` in the wrong place because I am not sure where I should use it.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your set up correctly, you have a circular dependency on the modules, so you need to `forwardRef` the imports for those. Using these modules should fix your issue:

#### `user.module.ts`

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
    forwardRef(() => TelvisionsModule),
  ],
  exports: [UsersService],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

#### `televisons.module.ts`

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: Television.name, schema: TelevisionSchema },
    ]),
    forwardRef(() => UsersModule),
  ],
  exports: [TelevisionsService],
  controllers: [TelevisionsController],
  providers: [TelevisionsService],
})
export class TelevisionsModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This seem to make it work but what I don't understand is in `user.module.ts` it's not using anything related to `TelvisionsModule` why do I need to import this module? Inside `televisions.module.ts` I am importing `UsersModule` because I am using its `UsersService`.  So I am a bit confused why `TelevisionsModule` need to be imported into `user.module.ts`?

Comment: Your `UsersModule` actually does use the `TelevisionsService` but indirectly via the `CanModifyGuard`. Because the guard is created in the context of the module, the `UsersModule` needs to have access to all providers that `CanModifyGuard` requires. While your `UsersService` doesn't use the `TelevisionsService`, the `CanModifyGuard` does

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying that, helps me understand more.  So I believe for e.g. if I have `MoviesService` in the future and its used in `CanModifyGuard` then `MoviesModule` would need to use `fowardRef()` to import both `TelevisionsModule` and `UsersModule` and these two also need to import `MoviesModule` correct?  If so, I wonder if there's a better way doing this?  As app grows, there might be lots other modules which means lots imports